# Two 'correct' (?) methods for differentiation and integration.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

So in my book of formulas there are two rules (among others) for differentation:

**x^n goes to nx^(n-1)**

and

**ln x goes to 1/x**

the corresponding rules for integration are:

**x^n goes to (x^(n+1)/n + 1) + c**

and

**1/x goes to ln|x| + c**

When I differentiate 1/x^3 I do so as follows:

1/x^3 = x^-3 so dy/dx 1/x^3 = -3x^-4.

Why when I integrate -3/x^4 can I not just do the following:

-3/x^4 = -3x^-4 so integral of -3/x^4 = -3* 1/-3 x^(-4+ 1) + c = x^-3 + c = 1/x^3 + c

Why must the answer be ln |-3/x^4|?

Comment: It is $\displaystyle\int \dfrac{-3}{x^4}dx=x^{-3}+c.$ Why do you say that the answer must be $\ln|-3x^{-4}|?$

Comment: I agree with what @mfl says but if one looks at the forth rule (in bold) [which is writen in the Cambridge booklet MF9] it suggests differently and that is the crux of my question. I doubt Cambridge is wrong so what am I missing?

Comment: The fourth rule says that $\int x^{-1}dx=\ln |x|+c.$ It doesn't say $\int x^{-2}dx=\ln x^2+c.$ In only applies when the exponent is $-1.$ For that reason the third rule holds only if $n\ne -1.$ In other case you would have to divide by zero, which is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

The "rules" for differentiation are
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} x^n &= nx^{n - 1}, \\
\frac{d}{dx} \log x &= \frac1x
\end{align}

I put the word "rules" in quotation marks because these are not
arbitrary rules that someone decided upon; they're simply facts that
inevitably result from the definition of differentiation.

One thing you *cannot* do with the rules is simply replace $x$
with some other expression (such as $x^4$) on both sides of the equation.
For example, suppose I know that $\frac{d}{dx} x^2 = 2x$, and I
wish to differentiate $x^6$.
I also know that $x^6 = \left(x^3\right)^2$.
So I might be tempted to write $2\left(x^3\right)$ and say
that this is the derivative of $x^6$. But that would be *wrong.*

Integration is just as uncooperative with naive substitution, if not more so.
It is true that
$$\int x^2 \; dx = \frac{x^3}{3} + C.$$
But you cannot just replace $x$ by $x^3$ in the functions on the left and right:
$$\int \left(x^3\right)^2 \; dx \neq \frac{\left(x^3\right)^3}{3} + C.$$

Similarly, while it is true that
$$
\int \frac1x \; dx = \ln \lvert x \rvert + c,
$$
this most emphatically does *not* mean that you can simply replace
the $x$ in $\frac1x$ with $x^3$ to get $\frac{1}{x^3}$ and then
have the logarithm of a multiple of *any* power of $x$ on the right.
Your book almost certainly *never* told you to do that.

---

As an aside, there are legitimate ways to substitute functions of $x$ into an
integral and get true equations as a result,
but they require you to change the variable of integration (the $dx$
in the integral) as well as the function being integrated.